# How can I make an Excel macro work without internet connection?

Tags: excel, vba, offline

I've created a macro in an Excel workbook to collect data in the field, typically without internet connection.

There are two sheets within my workbook: field form and Data.

There is one, very simple macro created where data that was input into the field form (sheet 1) is pasted into a table in the "Data" (sheet 2), and then the field form is cleared so it can be filled out again. Therefore, the macro is only working within these two sheets, in the same workbook.

For some reason, when disconnected from the internet, I get an error that says:
"Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

Is there any way to make my macros continue to work offline within this one workbook, which does not require any information from the internet?

Thanks!

J.

I checked and verified all security settings that may be blocking it (Options>Trust Center>Macro Settings>Trust access to the VBA project object model) and the error continues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would comment to ask questions but not enough reputation...

Macros within a file will always work without an internet connection, unless they need to query data from an internet source, as they are a part of the file, but they do not work in the Excel web app (Office 365 online).

Office scripts/Automate, the online "version" of macros, are not available offline because they are stored in the cloud vs the file.

I would double check how the macro/script was created. Since you need to collect data in the field without the internet, VBA Macros will be your best way forward. If the program was created with Office Scripts/Automate in the Excel web app, you will need to convert or recreate the process in the file's VBA editor using the Excel application on your computer.

If it was originally created in VBA in the file, you can double check the VBA editor to see if the program is there. The program could have been saved in a Personal Macro Workbook that is not downloaded to your computer for offline usage.

Comment: In short, press Alt + F11 and check the code as the error tells us its calling the internet.